# How to load a script using BHO in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, visual-c++, bho

I'm trying to load JavaScript files from my local file system to the browser using BHO as well as call a function from the same BHO.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? A quick Google search [brought up this guide.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149258/Inject-HTML-and-JavaScript-into-an-existing-page-w)

Comment: I am not interested to inject the portion of script but i want to load the complete script i.e xyz.js and using BHO want to call scripts functions.

Comment: If IE runs in "protected mode", your BHO can't read arbitrary local files, but it can read files in the "AppData\LocalLow" directory. Also,what do you mean by "call a function from the same BHO" Is that a Javascript function, or a C/C++ function implemented in the BHO. Please specify your problem more clearly. What have you tried?